# Get Data in a row with specific values

Tags: google-bigquery

I Have a series of data like example below:

| Customer | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-01-02 | 100 |
| a | 2022-01-03 | 100 |
| a | 2022-01-04 | 100 |
| a | 2022-01-05 | 100 |
| a | 2022-01-06 | 100 |
| b | 2022-01-02 | 100 |
| b | 2022-01-03 | 100 |
| b | 2022-01-04 | 100 |
| b | 2022-01-05 | 100 |
| b | 2022-01-06 | 090 |
| b | 2022-01-07 | 100 |
| c | 2022-02-03 | 100 |
| c | 2022-02-04 | 100 |
| c | 2022-02-05 | 100 |
| c | 2022-02-06 | 100 |
| c | 2022-02-07 | 100 |
| d | 2022-04-10 | 100 |
| d | 2022-04-11 | 100 |
| d | 2022-04-12 | 100 |
| d | 2022-04-13 | 100 |
| d | 2022-04-14 | 100 |
| d | 2022-04-15 | 090 |
| e | 2022-04-10 | 100 |
| e | 2022-04-11 | 100 |
| e | 2022-04-12 | 080 |
| e | 2022-04-13 | 070 |
| e | 2022-04-14 | 100 |
| e | 2022-04-15 | 100 |

The result I want are customer A,C and D only. Because A, C and D have value 100 for 5 days in a row.
The start date of each customer is different.

What is the query in BigQuery I need to write for that case above?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider below query ?

```sql
 SELECT DISTINCT Customer 
   FROM sample_table 
QUALIFY 5 = COUNTIF(Value = 100) OVER (
          PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(Date) RANGE BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        );
```

```
+-----+----------+
| Row | Customer |
+-----+----------+
|   1 | a        |
|   2 | c        |
|   3 | d        |
+-----+----------+
```

Note that it assumes **Date** column has **DATE** type.